# Elasticsearch with NEST to search for CommonTerms - missing documents

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, search, nest

I am using C# with NEST to communicate with Elasticsearch. I am trying to search for documents with a "content" field based on user-submitted text containing words, such as "unique test". The matched results can contain a 1 or a few of these words and the order does not matter (but the closer these words are to each other, in the document "content" field, the better).

So, for example, the search query should match these 3 documents:

```
{"content": "luctus, unique arcu vel, facilisis test. Praesentalne"}
{"content": "Maecenas lacus velit, very unique eu commo, tincidunt ut"}
{"content": "tempor test. Proin ipsum dui, porttitor vitae commodo mas"}
```

This is my query:

```
var searchResponse = await _client.SearchAsync<AuditModel>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .CommonTerms(c => c
            .Field(p => p.Content)
            .Analyzer("standard")
            .Boost(1.1)
            .CutoffFrequency(0.001)
            .HighFrequencyOperator(Operator.And)
            .LowFrequencyOperator(Operator.Or)
            .MinimumShouldMatch(1)
            .Name("content")
            .Query(model.Content))));
```

The problem is that this search query only returns:

```
{"content": "luctus, unique arcu vel, facilisis test. Praesentalne"}
```

This is the only result that has both words so I need this to be a higher priority than the other 2, but I would like to include all 3 if possible.

Is this possible with NEST? Thank you

Comment: I think you copied a little bit extra in there. Could you edit the post with the correct query? If possible, could you also verify the data you're testing against to make sure that this record is not in your database 3 times?

Comment: @EricMagers thanks for spotting this. Fixed. I have just checked and there are other data records in the database and there were duplicates. I forgot to set the filters for filtering by a date range! I still need to fix the common terms issues though.. thanks for this.

Comment: @EricMagers I've edited the question to focus just on the common terms problem because that duplication issue was just because of missing filters. Sorry about that.